# Why the color property isn't changing?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

The media query is changing everything but not the colour property. I wonder why? It is only working if I don't define the color property and leave it to default. Why media query can't change the color?

https://jsfiddle.net/6spv3mrf/

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  h1 {
    color: red;
    /*doesn't work*/
    background-color: yellow;
    /*works*/
  }

}

body {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#box {
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}

#text {
  min-height: 80%;
  margin: 25% 10%;
  padding: 10px;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
}

</style>
```

Comment: specifity issue, put the media query at the end ... `color: #000;` will always win

Comment: Example of what Temani has said above - https://jsfiddle.net/6spv3mrf/1/

Comment: @TemaniAfif actually not a specifity issue (both selectors are just `h1`)  , but a matter of later properties overwriting earlier ones if specifity is equal.

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question here on Stack Overflow, not just on a third-party site. See [mcve].

Comment: @Johannes yes sure if we should use correct words but i simply added a fast comment to show the issue :)

Comment: @Johannes rather, a lack of specifity issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move `@media` css **after** your `h1` css. Right now you are basically overwriting your `@media` properties with your normal css. If you add for example `body` inside your `@media` properties then your general `body` css should also be defined before the `@media` properties.

You can find more information in the official documentation:

> Find all declarations that apply to the element and property in question, for the target media type. Declarations apply if the associated selector matches the element in question and the target medium matches the media list on all @media rules containing the declaration and on all links on the path through which the style sheet was reached.

You can find full documentation [on the link](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/cascade.html#cascade).

```
h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  h1 {
    color: red;
    /*doesn't work*/
    background-color: yellow;
    /*works*/
  }
}

body {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#box {
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}

#text {
  min-height: 80%;
  margin: 25% 10%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

move the media query to the end of the css
[more info on why it works](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/cascade.html#cascade)

```
body {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#box {
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}

#text {
  min-height: 80%;
  margin: 25% 10%;
  padding: 10px;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  h1 {
    color: red;
    /*doesn't work*/
    background-color: yellow;
    /*works*/
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As we already wrote in the comments: The media query has to follow AFTER the general rule, since otherwise it is overwritten by the properties in the general rule (which apply to everything, so it's a matter of order):

Here's the (edited) code from your fiddle, which, BTW, you can as well put into a snippet here on SO:

```css
body {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#box {
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}

#text {
  min-height: 80%;
  margin: 25% 10%;
  padding: 10px;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  h1 {
    color: red;
    /*doesn't work*/
    background-color: yellow;
    /*works*/
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="text">
    <h1>
      Random<br> Text
    </h1>

  </div>
</div>
```